# How to know if PM2 runs my NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I've been wondering how one knows if PM2 or other similar apps run a NodeJS app? Not just knowing that the app is ran as a child process, but specifically know that PM2 is the one runs it.

I did `console.dir(process)`, but I had yet to find anything that referred to PM2.

Comment: you mean, want to know pm2 from code?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a lot of informations in the process environnement, pm2 use it to transfer variable into application.

You can see [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/1b79529ea0b71f9b673b4cd24d50edcb12e8b8e2/lib/ProcessContainer.js#L16) that the ProcessContainer (the wrapper around your application) set env var from `process.env.pm2_env`